# Separate comma-separated values within pandas dataframe cells

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am getting data from an API in CSV format, which I read into a pandas dataframe like this:

```
import io
import requests
import pandas as pd
response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.content.decode("utf-8")))
```

(As requested in a comment, here are the first 2 lines of `response.content.decode("utf-8")`)

```
dataset_version,dataset_generated_datetime,dataset_linked_data_default,last_updated_datetime,xml_lang,default_currency,humanitarian,hierarchy,linked_data_uri,budget_not_provided,iati_identifier,reporting_org_ref,reporting_org_type,reporting_org_secondary_reporter,reporting_org_narrative,reporting_org_narrative_xml_lang,title_narrative,title_narrative_xml_lang,description_type,description_narrative,description_narrative_xml_lang,participating_org_ref,participating_org_type,participating_org_role,participating_org_activity_id,participating_org_crs_channel_code,participating_org_narrative,participating_org_narrative_xml_lang,other_identifier_ref,other_identifier_type,other_identifier_owner_org_ref,other_identifier_owner_org_narrative,other_identifier_owner_org_narrative_xml_lang,activity_status_code,activity_date_type,activity_date_iso_date,activity_date_narrative,activity_date_narrative_xml_lang,contact_info_type,contact_info_organisation_narrative,contact_info_organisation_narrative_xml_lang,contact_info_department_narrative,contact_info_department_narrative_xml_lang,contact_info_person_name_narrative,contact_info_person_name_narrative_xml_lang,contact_info_job_title_narrative,contact_info_job_title_narrative_xml_lang,contact_info_telephone,contact_info_email,contact_info_website,contact_info_mailing_address_narrative,contact_info_mailing_address_narrative_xml_lang,activity_scope_code,recipient_country_code,recipient_country_percentage,recipient_country_narrative,recipient_country_narrative_xml_lang,recipient_region_code,recipient_region_vocabulary,recipient_region_vocabulary_uri,recipient_region_percentage,recipient_region_narrative,recipient_region_narrative_xml_lang,location_ref,location_location_reach_code,location_location_id_code,location_location_id_vocabulary,location_name_narrative,location_name_narrative_xml_lang,location_description_narrative,location_description_narrative_xml_lang,location_activity_description_narrative,location_activity_description_narrative_xml_lang,location_administrative_code,location_administrative_vocabulary,location_administrative_level,location_point_srsName,location_point_pos,location_exactness_code,location_location_class_code,location_feature_designation_code,sector_vocabulary,sector_vocabulary_uri,sector_code,sector_percentage,sector_narrative,sector_narrative_xml_lang,tag_code,tag_vocabulary,tag_vocabulary_uri,tag_narrative,tag_narrative_xml_lang,country_budget_items_vocabulary,country_budget_items_budget_item_code,country_budget_items_budget_item_percentage,country_budget_items_budget_item_description_narrative,country_budget_items_budget_item_description_narrative_xml_lang,humanitarian_scope_type,humanitarian_scope_vocabulary,humanitarian_scope_vocabulary_uri,humanitarian_scope_code,humanitarian_scope_narrative,humanitarian_scope_narrative_xml_lang,policy_marker_vocabulary,policy_marker_vocabulary_uri,policy_marker_code,policy_marker_significance,policy_marker_narrative,policy_marker_narrative_xml_lang,collaboration_type_code,default_flow_type_code,default_finance_type_code,default_aid_type_code,default_aid_type_vocabulary,default_tied_status_code,budget_type,budget_status,budget_period_start_iso_date,budget_period_end_iso_date,budget_value,budget_value_currency,budget_value_value_date,planned_disbursement_type,planned_disbursement_period_start_iso_date,planned_disbursement_period_end_iso_date,planned_disbursement_value,planned_disbursement_value_currency,planned_disbursement_value_value_date,planned_disbursement_provider_org_ref,planned_disbursement_provider_org_provider_activity_id,planned_disbursement_provider_org_type,planned_disbursement_provider_org_narrative,planned_disbursement_provider_org_narrative_xml_lang,planned_disbursement_receiver_org_ref,planned_disbursement_receiver_org_receiver_activity_id,planned_disbursement_receiver_org_type,planned_disbursement_receiver_org_narrative,planned_disbursement_receiver_org_narrative_xml_lang,capital_spend_percentage,transaction_ref,transaction_humanitarian,transaction_transaction_type_code,transaction_transaction_date_iso_date,transaction_value,transaction_value_currency,transaction_value_value_date,transaction_description_narrative,transaction_description_narrative_xml_lang,transaction_provider_org_ref,transaction_provider_org_provider_activity_id,transaction_provider_org_type,transaction_provider_org_narrative,transaction_provider_org_narrative_xml_lang,transaction_receiver_org_ref,transaction_receiver_org_receiver_activity_id,transaction_receiver_org_type,transaction_receiver_org_narrative,transaction_receiver_org_narrative_xml_lang,transaction_disbursement_channel_code,transaction_sector_vocabulary,transaction_sector_vocabulary_uri,transaction_sector_code,transaction_sector_narrative,transaction_sector_narrative_xml_lang,transaction_recipient_country_code,transaction_recipient_country_narrative,transaction_recipient_country_narrative_xml_lang,transaction_recipient_region_code,transaction_recipient_region_vocabulary,transaction_recipient_region_vocabulary_uri,transaction_recipient_region_narrative,transaction_recipient_region_narrative_xml_lang,transaction_flow_type_code,transaction_finance_type_code,transaction_aid_type_code,transaction_aid_type_vocabulary,transaction_tied_status_code,document_link_url,document_link_format,document_link_title_narrative,document_link_title_narrative_xml_lang,document_link_description_narrative,document_link_description_narrative_xml_lang,document_link_category_code,document_link_language_code,document_link_document_date_iso_date,related_activity_ref,related_activity_type,legacy_data_name,legacy_data_value,legacy_data_iati_equivalent,conditions_attached,conditions_condition_type,conditions_condition_narrative,conditions_condition_narrative_xml_lang,result_type,result_aggregation_status,result_title_narrative,result_title_narrative_xml_lang,result_description_narrative,result_description_narrative_xml_lang,result_document_link_url,result_document_link_format,result_document_link_title_narrative,result_document_link_title_narrative_xml_lang,result_document_link_description_narrative,result_document_link_description_narrative_xml_lang,result_document_link_category_code,result_document_link_language_code,result_document_link_document_date_iso_date,result_reference_code,result_reference_vocabulary,result_reference_vocabulary_uri,result_indicator_measure,result_indicator_ascending,result_indicator_aggregation_status,result_indicator_title_narrative,result_indicator_title_narrative_xml_lang,result_indicator_description_narrative,result_indicator_description_narrative_xml_lang,result_indicator_document_link_url,result_indicator_document_link_format,result_indicator_document_link_title_narrative,result_indicator_document_link_title_narrative_xml_lang,result_indicator_document_link_description_narrative,result_indicator_document_link_description_narrative_xml_lang,result_indicator_document_link_category_code,result_indicator_document_link_language_code,result_indicator_document_link_document_date_iso_date,result_indicator_reference_vocabulary,result_indicator_reference_code,result_indicator_reference_indicator_uri,result_indicator_baseline_iso_date,result_indicator_baseline_year,result_indicator_baseline_value,result_indicator_baseline_location_ref,result_indicator_baseline_dimension_name,result_indicator_baseline_dimension_value,result_indicator_baseline_document_link_url,result_indicator_baseline_document_link_format,result_indicator_baseline_document_link_title_narrative,result_indicator_baseline_document_link_title_narrative_xml_lang,result_indicator_baseline_document_link_description_narrative,result_indicator_baseline_document_link_description_narrative_xml_lang,result_indicator_baseline_document_link_category_code,result_indicator_baseline_document_link_language_code,result_indicator_baseline_document_link_document_date_iso_date,result_indicator_baseline_comment_narrative,result_indicator_baseline_comment_narrative_xml_lang,result_indicator_period_period_start_iso_date,result_indicator_period_period_end_iso_date,result_indicator_period_target_value,result_indicator_period_target_location_ref,result_indicator_period_target_dimension_name,result_indicator_period_target_dimension_value,result_indicator_period_target_comment_narrative,result_indicator_period_target_comment_narrative_xml_lang,result_indicator_period_target_document_link_url,result_indicator_period_target_document_link_format,result_indicator_period_target_document_link_title_narrative,result_indicator_period_target_document_link_title_narrative_xml_lang,result_indicator_period_target_document_link_description_narrative,result_indicator_period_target_document_link_description_narrative_xml_lang,result_indicator_period_target_document_link_category_code,result_indicator_period_target_document_link_language_code,result_indicator_period_target_document_link_document_date_iso_date,result_indicator_period_actual_value,result_indicator_period_actual_location_ref,result_indicator_period_actual_dimension_name,result_indicator_period_actual_dimension_value,result_indicator_period_actual_comment_narrative,result_indicator_period_actual_comment_narrative_xml_lang,result_indicator_period_actual_document_link_url,result_indicator_period_actual_document_link_format,result_indicator_period_actual_document_link_title_narrative,result_indicator_period_actual_document_link_title_narrative_xml_lang,result_indicator_period_actual_document_link_description_narrative,result_indicator_period_actual_document_link_description_narrative_xml_lang,result_indicator_period_actual_document_link_category_code,result_indicator_period_actual_document_link_language_code,result_indicator_period_actual_document_link_document_date_iso_date,crs_add_other_flags_code,crs_add_other_flags_significance,crs_add_loan_terms_rate_1,crs_add_loan_terms_rate_2,crs_add_loan_terms_repayment_type_code,crs_add_loan_terms_repayment_plan_code,crs_add_loan_terms_commitment_date_iso_date,crs_add_loan_terms_repayment_first_date_iso_date,crs_add_loan_terms_repayment_final_date_iso_date,crs_add_loan_status_year,crs_add_loan_status_currency,crs_add_loan_status_value_date,crs_add_loan_status_interest_received,crs_add_loan_status_principal_outstanding,crs_add_loan_status_principal_arrears,crs_add_loan_status_interest_arrears,crs_add_channel_code,fss_extraction_date,fss_priority,fss_phaseout_year,fss_forecast,fss_forecast_year,fss_forecast_currency,fss_forecast_value_date
2.03,2023-02-16T09:12:32Z,,2023-02-16T09:12:32Z,EN,USD,,1,,,XI-IATI-WBTF-TF072664,XI-IATI-WBTF,40,,World Bank Trust Funds,,Saint Lucia: Disaster Vulnerability Reduction Project EDF Single Donor Trust Fund,,1,This EDF Trust Fund financed by the European Commission aims to provide additional financing to the original Saint Lucia Disaster Vulnerability Reduction Project,,"TF612001,XI-IATI-WBTF","40,40","1,4",,,"EU-Commission of the European Communities,World Bank Trust Funds",,,,,,,2,"1,2,3","2015-09-01T00:00:00Z,2015-09-01T00:00:00Z,2023-12-31T00:00:00Z",,,3,,,"HIS-Urban\, Rural & Soc Dev - GP",,,,,,1202-458-7916,,,"1818 H St\, NW\, Washington DC - 22036",,4,LC,,SAINT LUCIA,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"1,1,1,1",,"11120,12230,14021,74020","11.0,11.0,4.0,74.0","+![cdata[Education facilities and training]]+,+![cdata[Basic health infrastructure]]+,+![cdata[Water supply - large systems]]+,+![cdata[Multi-hazard response preparedness]]+",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2,,,B03,,5,1,,2015-09-01T00:00:00Z,2023-12-31T00:00:00Z,6935451.25,USD,2023-01-31T00:00:00Z,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"1,1,11,2,2,2,2","2020-06-30T00:00:00Z,2022-08-31T00:00:00Z,2020-06-30T00:00:00Z,2020-06-30T00:00:00Z,2020-06-30T00:00:00Z,2022-09-30T00:00:00Z,2022-10-31T00:00:00Z","5519956.0,1236173.25,6935451.25,5341367.39,73469.52,87015.94,1098401.07","USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD","2023-01-31T00:00:00Z,2023-01-31T00:00:00Z,2023-01-31T00:00:00Z,2023-01-31T00:00:00Z,2023-01-31T00:00:00Z,2023-01-31T00:00:00Z,2023-01-31T00:00:00Z","Incoming Funds (Cumulative Paid-In Contribution )-as of June 30th\, 2020,Incoming Funds (Paid-In Contribution ) -  for August \, 2022,Incoming Commitment(Cumulative Signed Contribution)-as of June 30th\, 2020,Outgoing Commitment ( Total Grant Allocated Amount to Project ) - as of June 30th\, 2020,Allocation to Bank executed activities - as of June 30th\, 2020,Allocation to Bank executed activities -  for September \, 2022,Outgoing Commitment ( Grant Allocated Amount to Project ) -  for October \, 2022",,,"TF612001,TF612001,TF612001,XI-IATI-WBTF-TF072664,XI-IATI-WBTF-TF072664,XI-IATI-WBTF-TF072664,XI-IATI-WBTF-TF072664",,"EU-Commission of the European Communities,EU-Commission of the European Communities,EU-Commission of the European Communities,Saint Lucia: Disaster Vulnerability Reduction Project EDF Single Donor Trust Fund,Saint Lucia: Disaster Vulnerability Reduction Project EDF Single Donor Trust Fund,Saint Lucia: Disaster Vulnerability Reduction Project EDF Single Donor Trust Fund,Saint Lucia: Disaster Vulnerability Reduction Project EDF Single Donor Trust Fund",,,"XI-IATI-WBTF-TF072664,XI-IATI-WBTF-TF072664,XI-IATI-WBTF-TF072664,XI-IATI-WBTF-P127226,XI-IATI-WBTF-P127226,XI-IATI-WBTF-P127226,XI-IATI-WBTF-P127226",,"Saint Lucia: Disaster Vulnerability Reduction Project EDF Single Donor Trust Fund,Saint Lucia: Disaster Vulnerability Reduction Project EDF Single Donor Trust Fund,Saint Lucia: Disaster Vulnerability Reduction Project EDF Single Donor Trust Fund,SAINT LUCIA,SAINT LUCIA,SAINT LUCIA,SAINT LUCIA",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"110,110,110,110,110,110,110",,,,,,,,,,,,,XI-IATI-WBTF-P127226,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Upon inspection, many of the cells in the dataframe contain comma-separated data, of varying length. The comma-separated values are not surrounded by quotation marks, and some of the values contain commas escaped using backslashes. Example columns would look like this:

```
eg = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["A single value", "Three,separate,values", "This value contains a \,, and so does\, this one", pd.NA], "b": ["", pd.NA, "2,3,4","12,17"]})
```

I need to separate these cells into either a list within each cell or separate columns. I can do this one cell at a time, like this:

```
import csv
def to_list_of_strings(cell):
    if pd.isnull(cell):
        return []
    elif "," in cell:
        return next(csv.reader(io.StringIO(cell), escapechar="\\"))
    else:
        return [cell]

result = eg.a.apply(to_list_of_strings)
```

(I used `csv` in the hope that this will take care of other parsing that may be needed, such as quotation marks.)

The desired result looks like this (for `list(result)`)

```
[['A single value'],
 ['Three', 'separate', 'values'],
 ['This value contains a ,', ' and so does, this one'],
 []]
```

This can be slow across multiple columns and thousands of rows. Is there any faster vectorized way to do this?

Comment: can you post a testable fragment of `df` (not a series) ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest okay, I have posted a dataframe example with 2 columns

Comment: Can you also post the first lines of `response.content.decode("utf-8")`?

Comment: @mozway I added the first two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split strings with RegEx, it may fix backslash issue:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(?<!\\),')

def unescape_commas(s):
    return [x.replace("\\,", ",") for x in s]

s = pd.Series(["A single value", "Three,separate,values", "This value contains a \,, and so does\, this one", pd.NA])

s = s.fillna("")

s = s.apply(lambda x: regex.split(x))

s = s.apply(unescape_commas)

print(s.to_list())
```

Output:

```
[['A single value'],
['Three', 'separate', 'values'],
['This value contains a ,', ' and so does, this one'],
['']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my own regex solution - a vectorized version of the one posted by @angwrk.

```
(s
     .astype(str)
     .str.split(r'(?<!\\),', expand=True)
     .apply(lambda c: c.str.replace(r"\\,", ","))
     .replace("nan", pd.NA))  # assuming this is safe
```

This expands each series to several columns, which may be preferable in some ways to a list within each cell. I'm just not sure what other eccentric formatting (quotation marks, line breaks) might be hiding in the cells that I will need to take care of.